# Does InputSream needs to be closed if stream is made up using some String or byte array object in Java?

Tags: java, io, stream

I have a small piece of code.
I am creating an InputStream using the byte array and putting some data on server.

```
public void putStreamGetBytes() {
        try {
            String key = getKey();

            byte[] data = getTestData(getPayloadSize());
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

            putStream(assetNWK, key, stream, true, RESPONSE_OK, VERSION_1_1, null, true);
            validateBytes(assetNWK, key, data, RESPONSE_OK, VERSION_1_1, null, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleError(e);
        }
    }
```

I haven't opened any resource like a file or something. Do I need to close the stream to avoid memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you are not getting the expected output from your stream. So sometimes stream get block. To avoid these blockage you need to `flush()` the stream then `close()` it.

**`Here you are not using file or socket so memory leak would not happen but it's good practice to close stream after use.`**

Comment: I have the same feeling . Just need to confirm if there is some doc or something that suggests this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid memory leakage. you need to free the stream. to free the stream you need to call the close method in final block.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you are allocating for is the InputStream itself. Especially in cases of IOExceptions, depending on your usage of the code, this might be problematic anyway, i would suggest to use the try-with-resources syntax, if possible, like:

```
try(InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)){
......
}
```